# Find the value of each number which derives an average given a starting point, end point and total of numbers used.

Tags: average

Given an **average**, **a low number**, **a high number** and the **total amount of numbers** used (stated) to derive the average, is there a formula to determine what the value of each number was, that amounted to the average?

Example:

- Average amount: $272
- Highest amount: $548
- Lowest amount: $22
- Total numbers: 21 (e.g 21 people offering a range of bids on an item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.  You have four equations in $21$ unknowns.  You are given the lowest and highest, so really have two equations in $19$ unknowns. The fact that they are all within the range is not enough.  In special cases, like when you know all the bids are exact numbers of dollars and all but the last are $1$ more than the previous, you can solve it.

Comment: Even though I hoped the impossible was possible, I thought this may be the case. Thank you.